# How to replay a signal on a different frequency with Gnu Radio Companion and Hack RF

Tags: radio-interception, gnu-radio

I captured the traffic of a remote control for a LED light.
I have multiple of those LED Lights.
The payload seems to be the same for each device but the frequency(channel) differs.

For one LED light I lost my remote control, now I'd like to replay the captured traffic but on a different frequency.

How can I do this with tools like GRC and Hack RF (or other tools) ?